# Cake low recursive and non working bindmodel()

Tags: cakephp, recursion, model-binding, cakephp-2.3

I'm relatively new with Cake (2.3). In the cookbook and forum I can only find similar posts, but no one gives me a precise answer to the question. I just have a problem understanding and hope for your suggestions.

With a **recursive-Level of -1** in a Model, i realy **can't add** further models with **bindModel()**?

**Problem:**

when i put $this->Model->recursive to -1, i can't add other relations with bindModel().

If i set recursive to 2, the associates models are loaded within a find(). However, since this brings too many Associated data, I solve on-the-fly using $this->Model->unbindModel() on some models. Now, after i used unbindModel() to release some models, bindModel finaly works (?) to re-bind a Model.
i think this is can't be a clean way to bindAll (with high recursive-level) and then to unbindModelAll again, and re-bind the needed one once again?

I read something about Containable Behavior. Would this be the cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes containable behavior is very useful when you want data from selected model though we have associations with other models

i have used this features in my many of the project and it is provide good functionality to fetch data from associative model. look at the below link is very useful to understand  [ContainableBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)

let me know if this answer if enough for you.